# sp_OACreate Error Creating COM Component in SQL Server 2014/2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

The following script was extracted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql

```
DECLARE @object int;  
DECLARE @hr int;  
DECLARE @src varchar(255), @desc varchar(255);  
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'SQLDMO.SQLServer', @object OUT;  
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
   EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT   
   raiserror('Error Creating COM Component 0x%x, %s, %s',16,1, @hr, @src, @desc)  
    RETURN  
END;  
GO
```

When running it I get the following error: 
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
Error Creating COM Component 0x800401f3, ODSOLE Extended Procedure,  Invalid class string

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good. Using `sp_OACreate` and co is almost always a bad idea these days and you should be thinking CLR integration instead.

The fact that their *sample* uses [COM Objects that we're discontinued with the 2008 R2 version of the product](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540(v=sql.105).aspx) just means that you can't do too much damage by attempting to use the sample without modifying it.

If you *are* to use these procedures, you ought to be substituting in appropriate values rather than using the sample without modifying it.